# Firestore listener initialized with LifeCycleOwner argument misses updates when activity is paused

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my app I'm using a Firestore listener to listen for changes to a certain document. I init this listener using a LifeCycleOwner argument:

```
FireUtil.Events.getEvent( mEventKey ).addSnapshotListener( EventMainActivity.this, (documentSnapshot, e)
```

When I make change to this document in another activity (the one in which I added the listener is paused), and return to the initial activity, changes are not visible (a restart of the activity is required).

When I remove the life-cycle owner argument, the listener is triggered and changes are visible (but I need to manually clean the listener).

Is this intended behavior, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `addSnapshotListener` you attach a listener that gets triggered for any changes. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) the offical documentation. Apparently you [detach the listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) in `onPause()` method.

When you are passing in the `EventMainActivity`, [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#addSnapshotListener(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener%3Ccom.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot%3E)) will clean up the listeners automatically for you when the activity is stopped.

There is an altenative way for doing this and would be to use `get()` method to get the desired documents, which just reads that particular document once. Since it only reads once, there is no listener to clean up.

Comment: Yes, but I need to be triggered in case of updates (so the listener is on purpose).

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by moving the `addSnapshotListener` call (including he lifecycle owner argument) from the `onCreate()` to the `onStart()` method.